# count all num_rows, neglecting the limit

Tags: limit, mysql-num-rows

Is it possible to count all the rows in a table even if we add a LIMIT on our query?

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,10
```

for example the table contains 100 rows, how can I get that "100" with only one query even if there is a LIMIT on that query?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's easy use your PHP code to make `(0,10)` as varialbes like `($a,$b)`

then you do: `$count = $b-$a;`